# Keras data augmentation for Semantic Segmentation

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to implement data augmentation on both my image and mask for a semantic segmentation task as shown below. However, the ImageDataGenerator is able to read my images but it fails to read my masks. I am not sure where I am going wrong with this, it'll be great if someone can point out my mistake. Thanks in advance!

```
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale=1.0 / 255,
                         width_shift_range=0.1,
                         height_shift_range=0.1,
                         horizontal_flip=True)
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

    seed = 1
    image_train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=home_path,
        classes=[train_path],
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=seed)

    mask_train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=home_path,
        classes=[train_mask_path],
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='input',
        color_mode='rgba',
        shuffle=True,
        seed=seed)

    image_val_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=home_path,
        classes=[valid_path],
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=seed)

    mask_val_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=home_path,
        classes=[valid_mask_path],
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='input',
        color_mode='rgba',
        shuffle=True,
        seed=seed)
```

This is the error message that I am getting:

> Found 3816 images belonging to 1 classes. 
> Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes. 
> Found 1272 images belonging to 1 classes. 
> Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.

Comment: Include the complete error and trace (if any)

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it will not work the way you intended. Because masks and images have different generators, which will end up producing different outputs. Go for [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) instead.